# Python generator with increment

Tags: python, django, generator, increment

I have a loop:

```
total = 0
for s in sums:
    total += s[0]
```

where `sums` is a list of objects from the database, retrieved by Django:

```
sums = Source_types.objects.values_list('source_sum')
```

I'd like to move this code into a one-line generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
total = sum(s[0] for s in sums)
```

However, the Django ORM can be used to tell the *database* to do the summing here, using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total = Source_types.objects.aggregate(Sum('source_sum'))
```

Comment: `sum()`! OMG... I just forgot about it (in fact - I'm rarely have time for coding in Python) :-) thanks a lot. `aggregate` - thanks again, very useful